# Обложка mp3-файла не отправляется вместе с остальными метаданными

Tags: python, файлы, aiogram, mp3

Пишу бота на aiogram 3.

Бот отправляет пользователю mp3-файл (через FSIInputFile), в который, перед отправкой, я вставляю метаданные: артист, название, обложка. Метаданные сохраняются, аудио отправляется, с небольшим исключением: картинка не отображается на композиции в тг. При этом, если я скачаю этот трек на рабочий стол, например, а потом попробую вручную закинуть его в тг-чат, то обложка отображается. Сначала я подумал, что проблема в FSIInputFile, решил переписать все на aiogram 3.0, но результат тот же.

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, TPE1, TIT2


def change_metadata(audio_name, artist, title):
music = MP3(audio_name, ID3=ID3)
with open(logo_path, 'rb') as album_art:
    music.tags.add(
        APIC(
            encoding=3,
            mime='image/jpeg',
            type=3,
            desc='Cover',
            data=album_art.read()
        )
    )
    music.tags.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text=artist))
    music.tags.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text=title))
    music.save()
```

А вот так я отправляю файл пользователю в тг. Метаданные добавляются до отправки:

- Тут я aiogram 2 использую, результат тот же

  ```
        """ Выше ниженаписанного логика - получения названия mp3"""
    await laplayer_bot.send_audio(
        chat_id=uid,
        audio=open(music, 'rb')
    )
  ```

Comment: Покажите код, что как делаете. Приложите mp3 для теста.

Comment: Код добавил. mp3 и обложку можете любую взять